# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в предложении? Почему?

Tags: запятые, и

Я запуталась, и мне немного страшно, потому что не нахожу выхода из моих мыслей о детях.

Comment: И МНЕ НЕМНОГО СТРАШНО . Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь подлежащего нет, а СТРАШНО - сказуемое?

Comment: Извините, что я глупая такая! Голова вообще не варит! Возраст ... Спасибо, вы реально лучшие мозги России!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, нужна, потому что это сложное предложение. Союз "и" здесь соединяет две части сложного предложения.

Comment: Оборот, начинающийся с "...потому что", может быть общим для двух частей сложного предложения, поэтому запятая здесь на усмотрение автора. Аналогичный пример из Нацкорпуса: *"Я читал и мне сказали, что в этом доме от стихов в любом количестве не устают..."*; аналогичный пример из Розенталя: *"Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату"*.